# Is there a way to style password inputs with smaller dots for Safari on iOS 12?

Tags: html, ios, css, safari, ios12

For some reason the password input in iOS 12 Safari displays huge dots. I would like them to look as they look in Chrome. Is there a known way to style these inputs with CSS?

```
<input type="password" name="pass" />
```

This is how it looks in iOS 12 Safari:

[image: Safari ugly dots in input password]

This is how it looks in Chrome:

[image: Chrome dots in input password]

Comment: Still the case in 2022 – did you find a solution?

Comment: I haven't found a solution for it... But I think it's something somehow expected on Safari... It's a bummer, but it is what it is.

Comment: it's getting worse in 2023, any solutions ?